# Guidelines for secure iPhone application development

Tags: mobile, ios, iphone

Are there any security guidelines for development and assessment of (native) iPhone applications?

Comment: Please explain your question in more detail.  This really isn't the question for development questions.

Comment: I don't understand the hostility to this question.  I think this is a great question.  And I think questions about how to develop iPhone apps securely are perfectly on-topic for this site.

Answer (score 1):

Here are five suggested guidelines for iPhone application development and security considerations. In general you'll find them to be the same as security for any application development.
http://intrepidusgroup.com/insight/2010/05/top-5-iphone-application-development-security-issues/

Comment: Please add some content, rather than just a link.

Answer (score 1):

See also [Android API/development security pitfalls](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5107/android-api-development-security-pitfalls).  Many of the issues mentioned there are applicable to iPhone applications, too: e.g., insufficient protection of data in transit or in storage, insufficiently cautious handling of data from untrusted sources, risks from imperfect isolation of apps.